# content type for jpg image read from local drive

Tags: react-native, rest, format

My React Native 0.70 app reads a `jpg image` from local and upload it with `fetch PUT` to OSS. Here is the read from local:

```
  import ReactNativeBlobUtil from 'react-native-blob-util';  //v0.19.0

  fileData = await ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs.readFile(filePath); //or base64 if needed
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', fileData);
```

I tried image/jpeg, application/multi-form, application/octet-stream, application/xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded but none of them matches (the interpretation by OSS for signature verification) .

What is the content-type for `fileData` and `formData` generated above when uploading with fetch PUT?

Comment: In debug, fileData is a string and formData is an object with one key _parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried like this?

```
let formData: any = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', {
           uri: fileData.uri,
           name: fileData.name,
           type: fileData.type,
        });
        
        axios.post('upload', formData, {
           headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
           },
        });
```

Comment: fileData.type and fileData.name are not defined in console output